# How to keep dust from matte/rubbery plastic

Tags: dust, plastics

Some keyboards, computer mice, and other surfaces use this plastic coating that feels rubbery and looks matte. They are are somewhat "sticky", and are not easily *dusted* using conventional methods.

Is there an easy way to dust off these materials or otherwise keep them somewhat dust free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a product I've seen floating around called "[Cyber Clean](http://www.cyberclean.net/cleaning/en/Products/HomeOffice.html)", which essentially is some kind of special goo that can get into the groves of your keyboard and clean out all of the dirt.

[image: Cyber Clean]

The process seems simple enough, as [documented on the site](http://www.cyberclean.net/cleaning/en/Products/homeoffice/How_To.html):

1. Remove the compound from its packaging and knead it for about 10 seconds. This allows the compound to adapt to the pH value of your skin. Use only with dry hands.
2. Place the compound on to the surface you wish to clean and press firmly to allow Cyber Clean to enter into all gaps and crevices.
3. Pull the compound out. Dirt and bacteria are trapped inside the membrane system. Repeat cleaning action if necessary.
4. Put the compound back into its re-sealable packaging and close it carefully to ensure the compound remains fresh. Store the product in a cool and dry place, away from direct sunlight.

---

Your other viable option is using compressed air, which you can buy in a can, to clean the dust away.

[image: Compressed Air]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods that I can think of to *remove* the dust from these types of objects:

- ***Wash it***
  If the item is not going to be damaged from a dose of water, give it a quick clean with a sponge and some warm soapy water and rub it down with a clean towel afterwards, this will get rid of any dust on the material but would be a pain having to do it all the time.
- ***Sticky Tape***
  I am not sure if this would completely work but if you got a couple of lengths of sticky tape or duct tape and 'wax' the rubber as you would a hairy leg (if that's what you're into) then this might rip the dust particles away from the material.
  *Could also work with something like Blu Tack, just dab over the area and it should come away.*

There are however not many ways of *preventing* the dust from accumulating in the first place although one idea I did think of was that you could wrap the object in a clear film such as cling film. However this will likely be a stupid idea as the object will be rubbery and sticky for a reason and coating it would remove the sticky aspect of it - unless you ahve some mega clingy cling film!